# How to name column headers (column B to X) based on values in column A?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, worksheet-function

Consider the following excel worksheet:

```
  | ... | H      | I    | J
--+-----+--------+------+-----
1 | ... | obsDay | obs3 | obs4  ...etc
--+-----+--------+------+-----
2 | ... | 3      |      |     
--+-----+--------+------+-----
3 | ... | 4      |      |     
--+-----+--------+------+-----
4 | ... | 8      |      |     
--+-----+--------+------+-----
```

In `A2` to `A148` I have 147 `obsDay` values. I now need to make a separate column for each value. The values in cell `B1` and `C1' are respcetively there because of the formulas`="obs"&A2`and`="obs"&A3`

My question is: I cannot drag the formula to all other 145 columns. I I would drag the formula of `B1` to the right, `C1` gets value `obs`, with underlying formula `="obs"&B2`. I know I can fix column a like his: `="obs"&$A2`, but if I thne drag it to the right, `C2` gets value 'obs3' as well (with formula `="obs"&$A2` underlaying), while I need it to be `="obs"&$A3`, then `="obs"&$A4`, `="obs"&$A5`, etc..

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked into the [INDIRECT()](http://www.contextures.com/xlFunctions05.html) formula? Using it, you could put something like

`="obs"&INDIRECT("A"&COLUMN(A1)+1)`

in cell B1 and copy it to the right. There's probably a more efficient way of doing it, but that will work.

Comment: Thanks your your reply. It works, as described in the opening post. In reality however, the data is not in columns `A` to `C`, but in `H` to 'J'. I tried editing your formula: `="obs"&INDIRECT("H"&COLUMN(H1)+1)` but that doesn't work. IT just returns `obs`...what could be wrong? I have no clue, since I'm pointing to the right columns and rows, right?

Comment: No problem, I'm glad it worked for you. The COLUMNS(A1) is just a cheap way of getting a number that starts at 1 and increases as you copy it to the right. Leave the COLUMN() formula as it was in my original answer and swap the in the "H" like you've selected to give you something like `="obs"&INDIRECT("H"&COLUMN(A1)+1)`

Answer (score 1):

to translate from data reading down to going across, I use offset.

```
=OFFSET(Anchor_Cell,COLUMN(),0)
```

This will take the current column, and using offset, translate that into the number of rows to go down from the anchor cell.
Add or subtract from the `COLUMN()` number if needed